# How to enable Snappy compression on Avro-backed Hive table when STOREing from Pig using HCatWriter

Tags: hive, apache-pig, avro, hcatalog, snappy

I have a Hive table I created like this:

```
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set avro.output.codec=snappy;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table (
  aaa     STRING,
  ...
)
STORED AS AVRO LOCATION '/somewhere/my_table';
```

I now want to load data into this table via a Pig script:

```
...
do lots of stuff
...
STORE a_bag_of_data INTO 'my_table' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

All good up to this point (the data gets stored into the Avro files), but I want it to be compressed using the snappy codec.

I've tried to add (among other things)

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output true;
SET avro.output.codec snappy;
```

to the Pig script, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

If I insert data into the table using a Hive query, I can see in the table's underlying file that it is using snappy compression.

**Is there any way for me to tell HCatWriter to tell Hive to write to the table using Snappy compression?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about googling "pig avro compression"? And checking the result about https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2240 ??

Comment: Hi Samson. Thanks for your reply. I did come across that issue page. The two parameters they mention don't make any difference to the output when writing out to a Hive table via HCatalog. I think they're more useful when writing to an Avro file directly from Pig (which is what I'm currently doing to work around this problem, but I can see it will become a bit of a pain to maintain the schema in two separate places).

Comment: Actually, Samson, you were correct. I just did it again to be sure and setting those two parameters worked. Don't know what I was smoking the first time I tried it. Thank you.

Comment: `SET shoot.my.left.foot.while.cleaning.up.keyboard True` > no error message. Duh.